# Why do I get errors for std::sort using list of struct and lambda

Tags: c++, sorting, struct, stl, c++17

I have to use `std::sort` and lambdas for this, but I keep getting errors.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <iomanip>
#include <functional>

struct Song {
    std::string title;
    size_t release_year = 0;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Song& theSong) {
    out << std::left << "| " << std::setfill(' ')
        << std::setw(20) << theSong.title << " | "
        << std::setw(6) << ((theSong.release_year != 0)? std::to_string(theSong.release_year) : "") << " | ";
    return out;
}

int main() {
    std::list<Song> songs;
    songs.push_back({"them", 2021});
    songs.push_back({"between", 2019});
    songs.push_back({"separation", 2020});
    
    std::for_each(songs.begin(), songs.end(), [] (const Song& song) {
        std::cout << song << std::endl;
    });
    std::cout << std::setfill('-') << std::setw(34) << std::right << '\n' << std::setfill(' ');

    std::sort(songs.begin(), songs.end(), [] (const Song& a, const Song& b) -> bool {
        return a.release_year < b.release_year;
    });
    
    std::for_each(songs.begin(), songs.end(), [] (const Song& song) {
        std::cout << song << std::endl;
    });
}
```

If I use `std::list<Song>::sort` everything is fine but as I said I have to use the `std::sort`

The error is:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/functional:65,
                 from /home/adjective/Documents/Projects/Client/sdds/WS03/w3.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::__sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = std::_List_iterator<Song>; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<main()::<lambda(const Song&, const Song&)> >]’:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h:4899:18:   required from ‘void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = std::_List_iterator<Song>; _Compare = main()::<lambda(const Song&, const Song&)>]’
/home/adjective/Documents/Projects/Client/sdds/WS03/w3.cpp:31:3:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h:1968:22: error: no match for ‘operator-’ (operand types are ‘std::_List_iterator<Song>’ and ‘std::_List_iterator<Song>’)
 1968 |     std::__lg(__last - __first) * 2,
      |               ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from /home/adjective/Documents/Projects/Client/sdds/WS03/w3.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator.h:415:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> constexpr decltype ((__y.base() - __x.base())) std::operator-(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)’
  415 |     operator-(const reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator.h:415:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/functional:65,
                 from /home/adjective/Documents/Projects/Client/sdds/WS03/w3.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h:1968:22: note:   ‘std::_List_iterator<Song>’ is not derived from ‘const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>’
 1968 |     std::__lg(__last - __first) * 2,
      |               ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/iostream:39,
                 from /home/adjective/Documents/Projects/Client/sdds/WS03/w3.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator.h:1212:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> constexpr decltype ((__x.base() - __y.base())) std::operator-(const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const std::move_iterator<_IteratorR>&)’
 1212 |     operator-(const move_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator.h:1212:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/functional:65,
                 from /home/adjective/Documents/Projects/Client/sdds/WS03/w3.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h:1968:22: note:   ‘std::_List_iterator<Song>’ is not derived from ‘const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>’
 1968 |     std::__lg(__last - __first) * 2,
      |               ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/vector:68,
                 from /usr/include/c++/9/functional:62,
                 from /home/adjective/Documents/Projects/Client/sdds/WS03/w3.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_bvector.h:214:3: note: candidate: ‘std::ptrdiff_t std::operator-(const std::_Bit_iterator_base&, const std::_Bit_iterator_base&)’
  214 |   operator-(const _Bit_iterator_base& __x, const _Bit_iterator_base& __y)
      |   ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_bvector.h:214:39: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::_List_iterator<Song>’ to ‘const std::_Bit_iterator_base&’
  214 |   operator-(const _Bit_iterator_base& __x, const _Bit_iterator_base& __y)
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/functional:65,
                 from /home/adjective/Documents/Projects/Client/sdds/WS03/w3.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h:1879:5: warning: ‘void std::__final_insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = std::_List_iterator<Song>; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<main()::<lambda(const Song&, const Song&)> >]’ used but never defined
 1879 |     __final_insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator __first,
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: You can't use the standalone `std::sort` on `std::list`. The former requires random-access iterators, but the latter only provides bidirectional iterators. That's precisely why `std::list::sort` exists. Make `songs` e.g. `std::vector`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik so what STL container can I use? does std::vector work?

Comment: It should. What happens when you try?

Comment: On an unrelated note, the conditional expression often makes your code much harder to read, understand and maintain. As is the case of your use of it in the `operator<<` function. I recommend you go fo the much more readable `if-else` statement instead. Attempting to cram as much as possible into a single line or statement seldom leads to good code.

Comment: Regarding selecting between list and vector: Vector should almost always be the default go-to container. Only if you have very specific requirements should you use something else.

Comment: Thanks guys vector worked

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: `?:` has a bad reputation, but it has **semantics** that `if` lacks.  Instead of performing an arbitrary set of actions in each branch, it produces exactly one value in a shared context.  Here, aside from (theoretical) transient memory allocations, it’s free of side effects and serves to indicate that the `std::setw(6)` has its requisite one insertion regardless.  Putting either version into an `if` would invite mistakes like introducing a second insertion that wouldn’t be covered by the field width or removing the apparently useless `out << "";`.